# Update my Forked version of a project on Github

Tags: git, github

If I fork a project on Github, and that project gets updated, how can I make my fork get updated as the main project is updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the changes from the original project, merge them into your project, and push back to your Github repository.

It is not a good idea to automate this, generally.  (The upstream changes may result in a merge conflict or worse: a "clean merge" that breaks everything.)